# ReportViewer version for SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

I need to display SSRS 2008 reports in asp.net 3.5 application using Visual Studio 2008. Could you please let me know if ReportViewer 9.0 or ReportViewer 10.0 needs to be used to show SSRS 2008 reports.

If only ReportViewer 10.0 need to be used to show SSRS 2008 reports, please let me know if 
ReportViewer 10.0 can be used in Visual Studio 2008, as the development is being done in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, ReportViewer 9.0 only works with reports on SQL Server 2005; ReportViewer 10.0 only works with reports on SQL Server 2008. (See [here](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/08/11/reportviewer-control-look-out-for-appropriate-version-when-using-in-server-mode-remote-processing/) for links to MSDN)

Since you are using Visual Studio 2008 and want to work with SSRS 2008 reports, you should install **ReportViewer 10.0 Redistributable**. It will work at run-time but offers no design-time support. (See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/9316c4d5-fa1e-46ee-99de-371bfda863f4/) for an authoritative answer.) HTH.